# notation for numeral concatenation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set, I need to represent in a form: $\lbrace f(x) \ | \ x \in A \ \& \ P(x)\rbrace$.
However, have not been able to find the right mathematical notation for numeral concatination.
What is the correct notation I should use?

Example: a set of all possible concatinations of 1 and 2 of lenght 3.

$\lbrace 111, 112, 121, 122, \ldots, 222 \rbrace$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a three digit number (we have a positional number system) has the value 
$$ x_2x_1x_0 = \sum_{i=0}^2 x_i10^i $$
we have 
$$ \{111, 112, \ldots, 222\} = \left\{\sum_{i=0}^2 x_i10^i \biggm| x_i\in \{1,2\} \right\}. $$

Comment: Thanks. As I am quite new to mathematical notation of things, some quite obvious ways still escape me :)